# SQL Server Compact -- how to check for encrypted SDF file?

Tags: sql-server-ce

Is there a way to check if an SDF file is encrypted before calling SqlCeConnection.Open()?  Or do you just try to open it without a password and catch a specific error -- maybe SSCE_M_INVALIDSRCPASSWORD?